# dynamic calculation of li height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3shEE/182/)

The issue is that currently I am hardcoding the height when hovered to be 300, how do I do it such that it gets the height based on the number of

tag it has, so say there are 6

and each li is 50px height so then the height is 300.

I am talking about this line specifically:

```
 $(this).stop().animate({"height":"300px"},1000).addClass("dropped");
```

Also how do I make it such that when it's already expanded, and I click on it again it animates back un-expanded

Comment: Post your HTML code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the height of the ul and then set the #expandable animating height.

```
$("#expandable").click(function() {
    var ulHeight = $(this).children("ul").height() + 50;
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":ulHeight + "px"},1000).addClass("dropped");

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/G4s4G/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the ul like that with jQuery:

`$('#expandable').find('ul').height();`
...then just add the height of the span and you get the computed height for the animation :)

As for your other problem: Just check for your `dropped` class and animate it back if it is there:

```
$("#expandable").click(function() {
   var ulHeight = $('#expandable').find('ul').height();
   var spanHeight = $('span').height();
   var computedHeight = (ulHeight + spanHeight);

    if( $(this).hasClass('dropped') ) {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height": (spanHeight + "px") },1000).removeClass("dropped");
        return false;
    }

   $(this).stop().animate({"height": (computedHeight + "px") },1000).addClass("dropped");
});
```

See my Fiddle:
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3shEE/188/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$("#expandable").hover(function() {
     var _aH = (parseInt($(this).find('ul li').length)+1)*50
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":_aH+"px"},1000).addClass("dropped");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":"50px"},1000).removeClass("dropped");
});
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3shEE/184/)

basically, you need to calculate number of `li`s in your `ul` and then findout the `total height`.
Code assumes 50px to be the height of the `li`, you can make that one also generic, by grabbing the height of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to close the your `ul` using `</ul>` not `</nav>`

Secondly, to make it dynamic instead of harcode height, you need to calculate the total height of your list. Here is how you do it:

```
var sum = 50;

$('#expandable').find('li').each(function() {
   sum += $(this).height();
});

$("#expandable").click(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height": sum},1000).addClass("dropped");
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3shEE/186/)**</kbd>